# What does libcofi do?

Tags: c, memory

[This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11634/missing-libcofi-rpi-so-on-host-machine/37304#37304) rather vaguely states "libcofi-rpi.so is a hack to speed up certain memory operations."

Apart from the fact that the file is called `libcofi_rpi.so` on my machine, what exactly is libcofi ? Where can I find documentation for it ? Is it open source ? What problems does it solve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source isn't exactly top rate ([a 2013 thread from the archlinuxarm.org forums](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=5684)), but this seems to tally with your linked answer:

> For those who don't know the libcofi was a small library that had hand
>   optimized assembly version of 2 libc functions that could speed
>   applications using those functions a lot, when set to be preloaded.
>
> Libcofi has now been superseded by arm-mem, it provided more hand
>   optimized functions and is also faster. This is included in raspbian
>   by default, so make sure to install this, it would be shame to have
>   slower performance on Arch compared to Debian...

Looks like some enterprising soul optimised the [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) and [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) functions for Raspberry Pi, which ultimately sped up the programs that used them. Bouncing around Google gave me a few hints towards possible source code:

**Source:** https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=47832

> I believe Raspbian uses the libcofi optimized memcpy and memset via
>   the ld.so.preload mechanism (/etc/ld.so.preload), which is from
>   https://github.com/simonjhall/copies-and-fills/

**Source:** https://github.com/simonjhall/copies-and-fills

> Replacement memcpy and memset functionality for the Raspberry Pi with the intention of gaining greater performance.